# If G be k vertex critical is it k edge critical too?

Tags: graph-theory

G is k- vertex critical if and only if

for every vertex such v

$\chi(G-v) < \chi(G)$

as same we can define k edge critical

note that we know if  G be k edge critical it is k vertex critical too
but

the question is is:

If G be k vertex critical is it k edge critical too?
the answer is no but I need a paradox example to prove that is not true.

Comment: For multigraphs it is false :)

Comment: if there is a counterexample it isn't 3-colorable

Comment: @CarryonSmiling yes you right it is not correct but could you clear it by an example...?
thanks alot

Comment: It turns out we can do much better, there is a vertex-critical graph with zero critical edges: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9290354I

Comment: @CarryonSmiling It seems right thank you again ;)